# How to select an item by typing a keyboard letter in a drop down of xaml UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, combobox

I am developing the UWP APP wherein in one of the feature I am allowing user to pick the country from the drop down list. When user clicks on the list it displays the entire list of the country that is too big to pick a particular Country. My requirement is how I can add a logic where in the user can type a letter in the drop down and the list should automatically scrolled down to the first letter in the list that matches the letter user typed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IsTextSearchEnabled` and `IsEditable` properties to suit your needs.

For example:

Suppose you have a `List<string>` named **CountryCollection** as the data source.

```xml
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind CountryCollection}"
          ...
          />
```

This way you can enter text in the ComboBox, the ComboBox will match the data in the data source, if the drop-down list is open, it can also jump.

If your data source is not a `String` type, but a more complex structure, in order to implement this function, you need to override the `ToString` method.

```cs
public class CountryModel
{
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return Name;
   }
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding IsEditable, IsTextSearchEnabled property to the Combo box and it gives me a blank field in the drop down to type the letter But this is not what I want. I really want my drop down to automatically scroll into the list where the letter that user hits on the keyboard matches with the list item in the opened drop down list.

Comment: Hi, this solution is built into the control and is the easiest to implement. If you want to implement it exactly for your own purposes, consider using a `TextBox` with `Flyout` and listening to the TextBox's `KeyPressed` event to respond accordingly.